# I want to create a global array in order to listen for events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine that is invoked several times on my scene.

```
IEnumerator Save_assets(string file, int i, string name){

    var filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
    docPath = Application.streamingAssetsPath+"/files/";
    var temp_name = docPath+filename;

    downloaded_asset = false;

    if(!Directory.Exists(docPath)){
        Directory.CreateDirectory(docPath);
    }

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(temp_name)){
        WWW  www = new WWW(file);
        yield return www;
        //Save the image
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(temp_name, www.bytes);
    }

    /*  I really would like to have a sort of listener here doing something like:
        //pseudocode
        while(global.file != true){ //while not done
            yield return null;
        }

    */
    downloaded_asset = true;
    finished = false;
    tries = 0;

    go = GameObject.Find(name);
    go.gameObject.BroadcastMessage("paint_file", temp_name);

}
```

Once paint_file has been invoked the Update function on that very class
is constantly looking for a certain condition to happen, let's say it's "done = true;"

```
void paint_file(file){
    [...]//code
}

void Update () {
   var done = true;//let's pretend there's no code here, just  done = true
   if(done){
        Debug.Log("Finished: "+paint_file._filename);
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to set this var global.file = done,
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question title is about as descriptive as "I want to make a GUI in Visual Basic to track an IP address". For one, it isn't a question, it's a statement. For two, the title is telling us a solution which is invalid or poor practice, instead of asking for a valid or best-practice solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: Your comment is just as poor, It's the seventh day I'm working with c#, don't you think that If I knew what to look for I could have managed? Also, nice reference everyone watch tv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid ever using globals ( statics or singletons ) use direct callbacks instead or hook stuff up with component/object references

Also avoid Find, and broadcastMessage ideally as they are slow :-)

instead have:

```
var SomeComponentType myReferenceToThatComponent;

on Awake(){
    if(myReferenceToThatComponent==null){
        myReferenceToThatComponent = GetComponent<SomeComponentType>();
    }
}
```

Once you have a reference to a component you can access any public items on it eg:

```
myReferenceToThatComponent.done = true;
myReferenceToThatComponent.SomeMethod( true );
```

benefit is you can set that reference in the Editor, but if you don't set it leaving it null, it goes and tries to find it, and it only finds it once, any further use will uses the cached result and not have to use an expensive search again.

Your www should be surrounded with a 'using' as is the common practice to make sure it garbage collects when done

```
using ( WWW www = new WWW( url, form ) ) {
    yield return www;

}
```

The myriad of approaches to finding and getting components and objects is beyond the scope of this answer I think

Just remember Unity is preferably Component based which is quite different to the typical OOP Inheritance/Interface style of C# coding.

-

Way to structure Coroutines to run one after another waiting for one to complete:

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine( BaseRoutine() );
}

IEnumerator BaseRoutine() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        yield return StartCoroutine( ChildRoutine( i ) );
    }       
}

IEnumerator ChildRoutine( int i ) {
    Debug.Log( "ChildRoutine number: " + i );
    yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1 ); // Put your yield return WWW here for example
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try this method right away and possibly improve the code, one thing I'm not sure about is that I need to keep an eye on several objects, there are at least three subroutine downloading content and waiting for file.done = true; with the approach you showed me it appears that it's spreading to a single variable.

Comment: If you want to know when all 3 are done you will need to have them either set 3 seperate bools to true and only when all 3 are true proceed. Or have them increment a counter each and when that counter has reached 3 then run ( though this is dodgy if you accidentally have one run twice and fail to run another )

`if( done1 && done2 && done3 ){
  // now we are sure all 3 are completed
}`

Comment: unluckily there are several, could very well be 100 elements, that's why I thought about an array. each coroutine downloads a new item, each item can take a few moments or several seconds

Comment: sounds like your approach needs thinking thru then, you don't want to kick off 100's of coroutines all at the same time really. You might want a que where you run 5 coroutines at once then when 5 are done, run the next 5.

Comment: that's why I need done = true! the next coroutine is not starting until condition a and b are met. basically, it's downloading files from the web and it applies some filters on it, it's happening on at least three "monitors" and each monitor has no idea what the next one is doing

Comment: C# naturally has 100s of ways of doing things, Dictionaries, Lists and whats worse is it has 100s more ways you should not use, have been replaced by better ways. eg you rarely use Array any more just use a generic List which you can freely add/remove items from and its length changes to fit. Sounds like you need a big sit down with a book on C# I recommend Jon Skeet 'C# In Depth' and O'Reilly 'C# 5.0 in a Nutshell' and then of course Unity does things a bit different from the typical C# idioms as it is component based versus OOP / Inheritance. and there are NO books for Unity specific C# :-D

Comment: you are 100% right, It's only the seventh or so day I'm using c#, I'm overwhelmed with informations and I really find it difficult to follow  a  path or another. for instance, the tutorials said to use Find, here they're saying the opposite. it'll be better for me to buy a book, thanks for the recommendations, I'll check them

Comment: Also sounds like you misunderstand the glory that is unity coroutines

They are confusing at first but basically a coroutine allow you to do something, wait till its done, then do something else, even wait till that is done.. then do something else and so on, without having to sit asking in Update if something is finished. Go read up on Unity coroutines and how yield works and continues where it previously left off inside of the coroutine, as it sounds like you just need to nest a coroutine inside another coroutine and increment a counter

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I completely changed the way it works now, and apparently it's all good. Also, i'm buying the books.

Comment: good luck, on the 5th read through you should be an expert ;-)